# Cannot run SAS EG scheduler through SAS app

Tags: sas

I have set up a schedule program (the one sas have developed themself) which open my SAS EG and runs it, and it is normally working fine then I run on my local server, but if I run through SAS app it fails.

My question: Do you know a way I can schedule SAS EG running on a SAS app?

Comment: It seems like the scrip runs, but the SAS EG project does not run.
So what I mean by it fails, is that SAS EG does not run the project.

I cannot see any errors in the log though. Hope that gave you some clairfication on the problem.

Comment: What is your schedule program?  Do you mean LSF?  How did you configure the project to run on your local server, and how are you trying to configure it to run remotely?

Answer (score 0):

If your "schedule program" runs locally you may need to wrap your SAS code in `rsubmit` and `endrsubmit` statements to ensure it is submitted remotely (on the SASApp server).

See [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/connref/61908/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002590433.htm).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your code on the GRID , use rsubmit and endsubmit statements at the beginning and end of your code respectively.